# WinWord.exe won't close

Tags: vba, ms-word, taskmanager

I am running into issues creating a Word document Word from Excel using

```
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set letter = wordapp.Documents.Add
```

On first run it works fine, on second run it hangs. I think the issue is if I close the document I created using the Close Button in Word, it won't close WinWord.Exe. I think it has to do with whether I saved the document or not. How can I get around this?

I uninstalled/deactivated all of my Add-ins (I heard that could be an issue) to no avail.

Comment: I think you need `wordapp.Quit` to close the app properly. Do you have this line in your code?

Comment: Or you Menu File/Quit command on Word, but not only close document.

Answer (score 1):

try closing and releasing the objects

```
Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
Set letter = wordapp.Documents.Add

'release the letter object
set letter = Nothing
'quit the word appication
wordApp.Quit
'release the app object
set wordapp = Nothing
```

Comment: I recently found out that sometimes WordApp does not quit unless you make it visible first. Add `wordapp.Visible = True` before `wordapp.Close` is more promising. And make sure there are no other hidden winword.exe process running before your script.